# C# mvc window.open("_blank") genera error

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

Busco ayuda en relación a un proyecto de C# mvc que tengo. Pasa que quiero imprimir una imagen que está en un modal mediante un botón. El funcionamiento del botón, que abre una nueva página donde está la imagen sola, funciona (me da la opción para imprimir solo la imagen), pero, al momento de abrir esta nueva página, se produce el siguiente error:

"System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Inventario.Models.Equipo.Id_DescripcionEquipo.get devolvió null."

Entiendo que es como si hubiese vuelto a cargar la página sin la información del model (ya q el error salta en esa vista), pero no entiendo por qué se produce ese error ya que no hay ninguna función que haga eso en el botón. Cabe recalcar que la nueva página generada solo contiene la imagen que quiero imprimir, nada más.

Adjunto código.

HTML (traída con el controller)

```
@model Inventario.Models.Equipo
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Ver";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card mt-3" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="d-inline-flex">Detalles generales</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                    <i class="fas fa-qrcode mr-2"></i>Ver QR
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label">ID:</label>
                        <label class="form-label">@Model.Id_Equipo</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label">Descripción:</label>
                        <label class="form-label">@Model.Id_DescripcionEquipo.Descripcion</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label">Marca:</label>
                        <label class="form-label">@Model.Id_Marca.NMarca</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label">Modelo:</label>
                        <label class="form-label">@Model.Id_Modelo.NModelo</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label">Estado:</label>
                        <label class="form-label">@Model.Estado</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="@Url.Action("EquiposIndividual","Mantenedor")" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left mr-2"></i>Volver</a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Editar","Mantenedor",new {id=Model.Id_Equipo})" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-pen-square mr-2"></i>Editar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">QR</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row justify-content-center" id="QRImg">
                <img src="@ViewBag.imgQR" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:55%"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="ImprimirImg"><i class="fas fa-print mr-2"></i>Imprimir</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ImprimirImg").on('click', function () {
            var imgQR = document.getElementById('QRImg').innerHTML;
            content = window.open('_blank');
            content.document.write(imgQR);
            content.window.print();
            content.window.close();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hola!, el error de consola describe claramente el problema, Inventario.Models.Equipo.Id_DescripcionEquipo se encuentra devolviendo el valor de null. Asegurate que en tu base de datos tenga algun dato en ese campo o que este correctamente escrita la variable en tu modelo

Comment: Me faltó aclarar que todos los datos que llamo con el model están en la base de datos y, de hecho, aparecen en pantalla cuando carga la vista por primera vez. No es hasta q apreto el botón de "Imprimir" que me sale el error como si se hubiese recargado la página sin la información del model.

Comment: si no me equivoco, cuando asignas el valor de content = window.open('_blank') no asignas el tipo de dato en content. Prueba cambiandolo a var content =  window.open('_blank')

Comment: Ya probé y sigue saltando el mismo error.

Comment: Si entiendo bien tú quieres abrir una página vacía, volcar tu imagen y luego imprimir. window.open(_blank) no te sirve. Debes crear un html (imagen.html) e incluirlo en tu proyecto. Luego abres la url de ese html

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, realicé lo q recomendaste y funcionó!! No sé cómo agradecerte, ya me estaba desesperando quedar atascada en algo así.

Comment: @Soph Me alegro haberte podido ayudar en algo. Saludos